# C() function in R returning date column as double instead of date while fetching data from JIRA

Tags: r, jira-rest-api

I am trying to fetch data from JIRA using jirAgileR library. All the date fields are returning values in date format except for duedate. It returns values like 18466.00, 18473.00 etc. The only difference between duedate and rest of the date fields is that duedate is date type and rest of the fields are datetime.

```
library(JirAgileR, quietly = T)
library(knitr, quietly = T)
library(dplyr, quietly = T)

if (is.null(JIRABaseURL)) JIRABaseURL
if (is.null(username)) username
if (is.null(password)) password

fields1<-get_jira_issues(domain = JIRABaseURL,
  username = username,
  password = password,
  jql_query = "project in('My Project')",
  fields = c('duedate', 'updateddate', 'components'), 
  maxResults = 50,
  verbose = FALSE,
  as.data.frame = TRUE)
```

how can I fix the duedate in this code? updateddate is fetching data in correct format.

Answer (score 0):

This is an integer representation. Try parsing the date with `lubridate::as_date()`, e.g.

```r
lubridate::as_date(c(18466.00, 18473.00))
#> [1] "2020-07-23" "2020-07-30"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Without knowing details of your data frame, it would be something along the lines of

```r
fields1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(duedate = lubridate::as_date(duedate))
```

Double-check if the parsed date makes sense - the default `origin` is the Unix epoch of "1970-01-01". You can overwrite this by specifying the `origin` argument.